# How to mock a property setter on a PartialMock using Rhino Mocks

Tags: .net, properties, rhino-mocks

I'd like to prevent the real setter code being invoked on a property on a partial class.

What is the syntax for this?

My current code to stub out the *getter* (I'd like to also stub out the setter):

```
var user = MockRepository.GeneratePartialMock<User>(ctor params...);
user.MyProperty = "blah";
```

Something like this?

```
user.Stub(u => u.MyProperty).Do(null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a 3.5 sample that does what you need (I think your syntax above is 3.1 or 3.2).

First, I have a delegate for the property setter call:

```
private delegate void NoAction(string value);
```

Then use the Expect.Call with "SetPropertyAndIgnoreArgument" in addition to the "Do":

```
var repository = new MockRepository();
var sample = repository.PartialMock<Sample>();

Expect.Call(sample.MyProperty).SetPropertyAndIgnoreArgument().Do(new NoAction(DoNothing));
sample.Replay();

sample.DoSomething();

repository.VerifyAll();
```