# Stub setter in Rhino Mock partial mock

Tags: unit-testing, rhino-mocks, stub, partial-mocks

I'm following the accepted answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771665/how-to-mock-a-property-setter-on-a-partialmock-using-rhino-mocks) but I'm getting a `NullReferenceException`.

What I need is having a partial mock stub a property (both getter and setter) to behave like a stub (as a simple automatic property). Currently I am able to stub the getter but not the setter.

Is this possible?

EDIT: this is a simple example, I hope it helps explaining my problem.

```
public class SomeClass
{
 public virtual string SomeProperty
 {
  get{ return SomeMethodDependingOnDBOrAspSession(); }
  set{ SomeMethodDependingOnDBOrAspSession(value); } // I want to avoid calling this setter implementation
 }
}

var partialMock = MockRepository.GeneratePartialMock<SomeClass>();
partialMock.Stub(p => p.SomeProperty); // I want SomeProperty to behave as an automatic property
```

Comment: Code sample to illustrate the problem?

Comment: @JeffBridgman i added an example, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a `PartialMock` you can get auto-implemented property like behavior by using `PropertyBehavior` feature of Rhino Mocks. Given the class in your question, the following nunit test passes for me.

```
[Test]
public void TestPartialMock()
{
  var someClass = MockRepository.GeneratePartialMock<SomeClass>();
  someClass.Stub(x => x.SomeProperty).PropertyBehavior();

  string val = "yo!";
  Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => someClass.SomeProperty = val);
  Assert.AreEqual(val, someClass.SomeProperty);
}
```

If you don't need a `PartialMock` you could use a `Stub` which has property behavior by default. You'd simply replace the first two lines of the test with:

```
var someClass = MockRepository.GenerateStub<SomeClass>();
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot about adding virtual in the example but I'm already using this keyword in my code. The difference with your answer is that I need to use a Partial Mock, not a Stub. I updated my example

Comment: Updated the question to use a `PartialMock` instead.